# Error: Type declaration name doesn't correspond to current file name al nombrar fichero php

Tags: php, netbeans, clase

esta es mi primera pregunta en el sitio.

Tengo un problema al nombrar una clase en PHP, de solo nombrarla ya me da el siguiente error:

```
Type declaration name doesn't correspond to current file name.
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para resolver esta situación?

dejo una captura:[image: Problema-nombrar-clase]

Comment: *Type declaration name doesn't correspond to current file name*, o lo que es lo mismo, tu clase no se llama igual que tu fichero: `Usuario != usuario`

Comment: Correccion no es un error de PHP es un error marcadi por el highligh del IDE

Comment: si alguna de las respuesta que te dieron responde tu duda recuerda marcarla como respondida/resuelta.

Answer (score 5):

**Corrección:** no es un error de PHP, es un error marcado por el `highlight` (característica del [depurador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depurador)) del [IDE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado).

Adicionalmente, si lo ejecutas, entonces saltará un error o excepción, cuyo mensaje será que la Clase no se encontró. Para evitar esto, el IDE se adelanta y te muestra ese tipo de información.

Esto sucede porque en el [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) se especifica que el fichero (archivo PHP) debe tener el mismo nombre que la Clase, siendo este nombre [sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_a_may%C3%BAsculas_y_min%C3%BAsculas). También se recomienda que las Clases sean nombradas en [PascalCase](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) (primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula).

Por ejemplo para crear la Clase Usuario el archivo debería nombrarse:

```
Usuario.php
```

y dentro el código debería ser:

```
<?php

class Usuario 
{
   //contenido
}
```

Y si tenemos una Clase con un nombre compuesto, por ejemplo `FileLoader`, entonces, el fichero o archivo de PHP se debe llamar:

```
FileLoader.php
```

y dentro el código debería ser:

```
<?php

class FileLoader 
{
   //contenido
}
```

Comment: Gracias @mauricio-contreras